# Sort array of objects by value using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by the `average` property in descending order - so the largest `average` is first - but am not able to using underscore.js. Below is my attempt:

```
var jsonData = [
{
    "title": "Dear Kitten",
    "totalCount": 1689,
    "average": 241
},
{
    "title": "Weird Things All Couples Fight About",
    "totalCount": 9966,
    "average": 1424
},
{
    "title": "If Disney Princesses Were Real",
    "totalCount": 16567,
    "average": 2367
},
{
    "title": "Secret Tricks With Everyday Objects",
    "totalCount": 24884,
    "average": 3555
},
{
    "title": "The Coolest Travel Hacks",
    "totalCount": 41847,
    "average": 8369
},
{
    "title": "5 Ways You're Drinking Coffee Wrong",
    "totalCount": 55673,
    "average": 7953
},
{
    "title": "The Perfect Way To Pour A Beer",
    "totalCount": 58097,
    "average": 58097
},
{
    "title": "Fruit You're Eating Wrong",
    "totalCount": 65570,
    "average": 32785
},
{
    "title": "Your Cat Is Judging You",
    "totalCount": 78952,
    "average": 11279
},
{
    "title": "3rd Date vs 30th Date",
    "totalCount": 84394,
    "average": 14066
}
];

console.log(_.sortBy(jsonData, "average"));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7h9cu6p/)

Comment: ?? Looks like it's working just fine.  The result is sorted in order of the value of the "average" property.

Comment: You aren't including underscore in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y7h9cu6p/1/

Comment: @RobM. ? it was there when I tried it just now. (It's an "external resource" in the OP's fiddle.)

Comment: @Pointy that's odd, I only see jQuery 2.1.3 and an error in the console that `_` is undefined *oops* see it in external resources now

Comment: @Pointy in my console, it does not appear sorted. Just ouputs the same json object.

Comment: @RobM. try in firefox. might be jsfiddle cross domain issue.

Comment: I'm using Firefox and it works OK completely. No errors, and the result is sorted.

Comment: hmm, this is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/8m8zMK8.png (perfect way to beer should appear on top etc..)

Comment: That looks like it is correctly sorted. Is the problem that you want it in the opposite order, with the largest `average` first? Use `.reverse()` after the sort, or provide your own `iteratee` that reverses it, e.g. `function( item ) { return -item.average; }`.

Comment: Right - sorting by default gives you smallest to largest (ascending order).

Comment: You can't sort an object...

Comment: @Mottie - it's an array.

Comment: From the first sentence: `Trying to sort a JSON object`

Comment: @Mottie well arrays are objects :)  (If you look at the jsfiddle, it's an array.)

Comment: @Mottie - Look at the code. `jsonData` is an array. (It's also arguably not *JSON* at all, but that's just a minor error of terminology.)

Comment: You don't have JSON. You have a JS array containing JS objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you wanted the array to be sorted in *descending* order by `average`, instead of the default ascending order.

You could do this by providing a custom `iteratee` to the `_.sortBy()` function:

```
_.sortBy( jsonData, function( item ) { return -item.average; } )
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7h9cu6p/2/)

But I don't recommend that. It would be much better to simply use the native JavaScript `[].sort()` method and provide it a comparison function:

```
jsonData.sort( function( a, b ) { return b.average - a.average; } )
```

[Better fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7h9cu6p/3/)

If you were sorting a very large array, this would also be faster than using `_.sortBy()`. Look at the source code for `_.sortBy()` to see why:

```
_.sortBy = function(obj, iteratee, context) {
  iteratee = cb(iteratee, context);
  return _.pluck(_.map(obj, function(value, index, list) {
    return {
      value: value,
      index: index,
      criteria: iteratee(value, index, list)
    };
  }).sort(function(left, right) {
    var a = left.criteria;
    var b = right.criteria;
    if (a !== b) {
      if (a > b || a === void 0) return 1;
      if (a < b || b === void 0) return -1;
    }
    return left.index - right.index;
  }), 'value');
};
```

It's doing quite a bit of work in addition to the `.sort()` call - and this code is just the tip of the iceberg, the helper functions it calls like `cb()` do a lot of work too.

Why do all that when it's just as easy to call `.sort()` directly yourself?

Also, it takes a close reading of that lengthy `.sortBy()` source to be sure that it does a *numeric* sort instead of a lexicographic sort - and [the documentation doesn't say](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)!

A lexicographic sort (aka alphabetic sort) is where the values are sorted *as strings*, not as numbers. So for example it would use this order:

```
[ 1424, 2367, 241, ... ]
```

When you call the native array `.sort()` yourself, you can easily verify that it uses a numeric sort: the value `b.average - a.average` is always a number.